# Getting general solution to PDE as a function of characteristic curves

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

When we use the method of characteristics to solve a quasilinear PDE 
\begin{equation}
a(x,y,u)u_x + b(x,y,u)u_y = c(x,y,u),
\end{equation}
we use the method of characteristics to find the characteristic equations defined by 
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{a}{b} , \quad \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{c}{a}
\end{equation}
Then once we solve the above ODE's in terms of the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$, we relate the two through an arbitrary function $c_2 = f(c_1)$. I don't understand **why** we do this though. I've searched everywhere, but I can't find a good description explaining this step. The best I can find is along the lines of:

> If you can find characteristic curves $u_1(x,y,u)=c_1$ and $u_2(x,y,u)=c_2$, then the general solution to the PDE can be written as an implicit function satisfying the equation $$F(u_1,u_2) = F(c_1,c_2) = 0$$ for some arbitrary function $F$. We can then solve for $c_2$ to recover $c_2 = f(c_1)$ for some $f$.

The problem I have with the above though, is again **why** we can we write the general solution to the PDE as $F(c_1,c_2) = 0$?

There is a gap in my knowledge here that I can't find the answer to anywhere, so I would very much appreciate someone's help. Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics

Comment: I obviously read that... Doesn't answer my question though

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elimination of constants in pde's. How does it appears the arbitrary function in the general solution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2084707/elimination-of-constants-in-pdes-how-does-it-appears-the-arbitrary-function-in)

Comment: Roughly speaking the equation is first order, so it should have a one-parameter family of solutions.